# TableView Swipe to Delete: How to Programmatically Un-swipe

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am using a the swipe to delete feature in the tableview to delete selected cells. You swipe it to the left to reveal a delete button.  My code works well and deletes like it should.

I am also including a UIAlertController to give the user of the app a single last chance from making a mistake. What I would like to do is if the user selects "Cancel" is have the cell "un-swipe" and return to its original position. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Take a copy of all your cell data before the deleteRowsAtIndexPath and if they tap cancel, just swap it back in and reload your tableView.

Answer (score 7):

You can turn off editing on the tableView

```
[self.tableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];
```

Comment: This is no longer required (nor does it actually work) as of iOS11.  To dismiss the swipe view programmatically, call the "completionHandler" (third parameter to the UIContextualAction.Handler when you setup the swipe action) with either a true or false value. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49995770/1204250

Answer (score 2):

I came across this question trying to do the same thing.  I thought there had to be a better solution that reloading the table, so I did some further research and found the following.

```
tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)
```

here's a little more code (Swift 3) to show it in use

```
    // Custom cell edit actions
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") {(rowAction: UITableViewRowAction, indexPath: IndexPath) -> Void in

        let refreshAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Delete", message: "Are you sure you want to delete this item.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

        refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
            let context = self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext
            context.delete(self.fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath))

            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                let nserror = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }
        }))

        refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
            // if the user presses cancel, slide the cell back
            tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)
        }))

        self.present(refreshAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    let editAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Edit") { action, index in
        print("edit button tapped")
    }

    editAction.backgroundColor = .orange


    return [editAction, delete]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar question and found your question searching for an answer. Based on the lack of answers here, I assumed I had to figure it out myself. Here is my issue and how I solved it. I hope it works for you, since I solved it extremely simple.

I have an app with a start screen that shows a table with several tracks. When you select a track you can either show the track details, show the track on a map (with MapView) or delete the track.

[image]

However, when you first use the app, the table is empty and shows a single table cell: "No saved tracks".

[image]

This means the table is empty and you can't show track details, a track map or delete the track. I wanted to make sure that if the table is empty, you get a different message and the left swipe is undone.

[image]

The code is an overige of funk -tableView:editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let selectedRow = indexPath.row

    guard self.savedTracks.count > 0 else {
    //There are no saved tracks, the action cannot be executed.
        let faultAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "No tracks", handler: { (action, indexPath) -> Void in

            self.trackOverviewTable.reloadData() //Simply reload the table view after the action button is hit.
        })

        return [faultAction]
    }

    //Show track details
    let detailsAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Details") { (action, indexPath) -> Void in

        print("I now selected the track details view.\n")
        self.newTrack = self.savedTracks[selectedRow]
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showTrackDetails", sender: self)
    }

    //Show track map
    let mapAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Map") { (action, indexPath) -> Void in

        print("I now selexted the track map view.\n")
        self.newTrack = self.savedTracks[selectedRow]
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showTrackMap", sender: self)
    }

    //Delete the selected track
    let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Delete") { (action, indexPath) -> Void in

        print("I now pressed the delete button.\n")
        self.savedTracks.removeAtIndex(selectedRow)
        if self.savedTracks.count > 0 {
            self.trackOverviewTable.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        } else {
            self.trackOverviewTable.reloadData()
        }
    }

    detailsAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 21.0/255.0, green: 175.0/255.0, blue: 253.0/255.0, alpha: 0.8)
    mapAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 37.0/255.0, green: 155.0/255.0, blue: 253.0/255.0, alpha: 0.8)

    return [deleteAction, mapAction, detailsAction]
}
```

The important part here is the "guard else" statement, where the code is executed when there is no track saved. Basically, the swipi shows a different message "No tracks" and when this action button is clicked, the table will be reloaded and the swipe is undone. Since you use a UIAlertController, the same principle applies. The above methods works almost exactly the same as a UIAlertController and you can also reload your table after the user selects the "Cancel" button.

As I said, it is extremely simple and perhaps not meeting your expectations, but it does unswipe your left swipe after the user click "Cancel". I hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have followed this approach and it works quite well

```
private func onDeleteNote(noteIdx: Int) {
        let noteToDelete: Note = myNotes[noteIdx]
        
        let alertViewController = UIAlertController(title: "¿Would you like to delete this note?", message: "The Note \(noteToDelete.title) will be delete", preferredStyle: .alert)
        
        alertViewController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .destructive) { (UIAlertAction) in
            print("Delete note")
        })
        alertViewController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (UIAlertAction) in
            print("Delete note was cancel")
            self.myNotesTable.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: noteIdx, section: 0)], with: .right)
        })
        
        present(alertViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        
    }
```

When the user cancel the operation I try to reload this table cell for discarding the swipe state.