# Swift 4 - tableview set editing false doesn't dismiss row actions

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

This is my code -

```
    func rowActionDelete(indexPath: IndexPath, reminder: Reminder){

        do {
            self.managedObjectContext.delete(self.listOfSavedItems[indexPath.row] as! NSManagedObject)
            try self.managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch {
            let saveError = error as NSError
            print(saveError)
        }
        self.tableViewItems.setEditing(false, animated: true)
        self.listOfSavedItems.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        self.tableViewItems.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    }
```

This function is called from trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt.

```
@available(iOS 11.0, *)
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {

    self.selectedRowReminder = Reminder(withFetchedObject: self.listOfSavedReminders[indexPath.row] as! NSManagedObject)

    // Delete
    let delete = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: " ") { (action, view, handler) in
        self.rowActionDelete(indexPath: indexPath, reminder: self.selectedRowReminder)
    }
    delete.backgroundColor = .red
    delete.image = UIImage(named: "Trash")

    // Share
    let share = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: " ") { (action, view, handler) in
        self.rowActionShare(reminder: self.selectedRowReminder)
    }
    share.backgroundColor = .gray
    share.image = UIImage(named: "Share")

    // Edit
    let edit = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: " ") { (action, view, handler) in
        self.rowActionEdit(reminder: self.selectedRowReminder)
    }
    edit.backgroundColor = .darkGray
    edit.image = UIImage(named: "Edit")

    let configuration = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [delete, edit, share])
    return configuration
}
```

As you can see I'm setting the edit mode to false. However, my row actions are not being dismissed.

[image]

What am I missing? The delete is happening ok. But the row actions remain, and this is leaving a white space in place of where the deleted row was. The table is not updating to remove the row. But if I click anywhere else, it redraws the table and everything is ok until I do the next delete. I've tried setNeedsLayout(), layoutIfNeeded() but no effect. So either this is one issue, or two issues combined. Please don't suggest reloadData(). I know that'll resolve all these issues but that's not a recommended approach.

Comment: I don't think you read my whole question (check the last line please).

Comment: Try beginUpdates() and endUpdates() methods before and after deleting the row

Comment: how you are calling `rowActionDelete`? Can you try calling from main thread?

Comment: why you not try with delegate method `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration?`

Comment: @Mani - Apple says so - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614862-reloaddata

Comment: @MBN - Tried that, no effect.

Comment: @Kamran - It's being called from the trailing swipe configuration.

Comment: @Anbu.karthik - Yes, that's where it's called from. I've updated the question,

Comment: @DS. please check my answer. I had the same issue and figured it out just now, thanks to your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**EDIT:**

I had the same issue and I found that `tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)` is not necessary anymore. All you need to do is to pass `true` to the `UIContextualAction` handler and the rest will be taken care of. Here is what I do:

```
@available(iOS 11, *)
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, view, handler) in
        self.deleteRow(at: indexPath)
        handler(true) // Will do the animation
    }

    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction])
}

// Delete

func deleteRow(at indexPath: IndexPath) {
    items.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .left)
}
```

Comment: Perfect, that was it! Thank you so much! I still called the function as I was doing in my original post, just added the handler(true) as you suggested and that did the trick.